# how to quantify sharpness of "threshold"

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I have function $f(x)$ that starts as concave up and becomes concave down after some point (the "threshold").

What's the mathematically rigorous way to quantify the sharpness of the "threshold"? I think it is safe to define as a threshold any point where the direction of concavity changes (second deviation of $f$ becomes zero and third deviation is not zero, if memory serves), but I don't know how to capture the "sharpness".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you refer to as a "threshold" is generally called a point of inflection. Indeed, a point of inflection is defined as any point where a function changes concavity (i.e. where the second derivative of the function changes sign). Now, as for characterizing the sharpness, possibly the easiest way would be to find the third derivative of the function, which would tell you how quickly the second derivative is changing over the interval you are looking for.

Comment: what worries me is that the third derivative (or any other derivative for that matter) are only evaluated on a specific point X0. In general I have second thoughts as to how well inflection points convey the idea of a threshold. E.g., in the case of experimental data and not nice analytic functions you could have multiple inflection points and I don't know how you would measure the concept of the data points moving rapidly from one plateau to another.

Comment: You bring up a fair point, but if we are indeed dealing with experimental data, then you can only go so far as to provide a curve of best fit and analyze that curve. Obviously, the curve won't be a perfect fit, which is where your measures of residuals will come into play. My thoughts were that if you used the 3rd deriv, you can use smaller and smaller step sizes on either side of your suspected inflection point, and the larger in absolute value your 3rd deriv is, the more likely you are dealing with a inflection point. Its by no means ideal, but I think it could still serve your purposes.